# La aplicación se detuvo - Filtro Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

quiero filtrar un Recyclerview. 
Para eso tengo un EditText que al tipear en él, debería filtrar.

```
editTxtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

       filter(editable.toString());
   }
});
```

A continuación verán el método que toma lo que se tipeó, revisa si la palabra es contenida en la descripción de cada producto de la lista y si es true, agrega el producto a una nueva lista filtrada y reducida.

```
private void filter(String text){

    List<Producto> filteredProducts = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Producto p : productos){

        if (p.getStmpdHDESCRP().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())){
            filteredProducts.add(p);
        }
    }

    productoAdapter.filterList(filteredProducts);
}
```

Y por último el código en el Adapter.

```
public void filterList(List<Producto> filteredProducts){

    this.listadoProductos = filteredProducts;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

El problema es que se detiene la App al querer tipear en el EditText y arroja el siguiente mensaje el Log:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object
>   reference
>           at ar.com.amtech.cabodiazure.activities.SecondActivity.filter(SecondActivity.java:123)
>           at ar.com.amtech.cabodiazure.activities.SecondActivity.access$000(SecondActivity.java:27)
>           at ar.com.amtech.cabodiazure.activities.SecondActivity$1.afterTextChanged(SecondActivity.java:74)

Qué estoy haciendo mal? 
Será que la lista productos del for en el método private void filter(String text), está vacía? Porque veo que no hace referencia a la lista que tomo desde acá:

public void onResponse(Call> call, 
                             Response> response) {

```
         List<Producto> productos = response.body();
```

Es la primera vez que intento hacer ésto... y se nota.

Gracias,
Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declara la lista que obtienes el response global

```
private List<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<>();
```

Luego en el metodo del response asignale el valor de respuesta

```
productos = response.body();
```

Por ultimo en el filtro, le asignas esa respuesta a la lista que vas a iterar

```
List<Producto> filteredProducts = new ArrayList<>();
filteredProducts = productos;
```

De esta forma `filteredProducts` va a tener los valores que se solicitaron anteriormente y se almacenaron en la otra lista, pero tene en cuenta que si esta tarea es asincrona y presionas antes en el editttext para buscar antes que esten los datos, te va a saltar un problema, para esto deberias esperar a que la informacion se solicite para luego poder buscarla, o poner una excepcion de que no hay datos aun para buscar.

El problema era que cuando declarabas tu lista en el filter, declarabas una nueva lista vacia sin datos de tipo `Producto`

Comment: Excelente! Gracias.... me funcionó. Lo había pensado y tenía declarada la List sin instanciar. O sea.. me faltaba el  = new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 0):

Correcto, la lista es nula. En la respuesta estas creando una variable local con el mismo nombre que el field *productos* de la clase, pero no es lo mismo. Asignas el valor a esta variable local pero la otra variable de clase, que es la que utilizas en el método filter se queda sin valor y por eso arroja ese error.

La solución es asignar la respuesta a la variable global:

```
  this.productos = response.body();
```

Espero que esto lo solucione. Un saludo.